# Issue with Apache mod_proxy

Tags: docker, tomcat, server, apache2, tomcat9

I have a tomcat server running inside a docker with IP 172.17.0.2:8080 with a webapp named "app1".

And I have an Apache server running for redirecting requests to the tomcat server with a default page showing "It Works!"
This is my Virtual Host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ServerName 172.17.0.2
    ProxyPass /app1 http://172.17.0.2:8080/app1
    ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://172.17.0.2:8080/app1
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, 
If I hit localhost then the "It Works!" page loads.

If I hit localhost/app1 then tomcat webapp page loads.

If I hit 172.17.0.2:8080/app1 then tomcat webapp page loads.

If I hit 172.17.0.2/app1 then no page is loaded, and the error shown is "Connection Refused".
Here I expect to load the tomcat webapp page as I have set the ServerName to 172.17.0.2

Basically what I want to do is to run multiple servers on the same machine inside docker containers rather than running single server on multiple machines.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your Apache HTTPD is only listening at `localhost`. Off topic.

Comment: How can I listen to other IPs?